# SharedPreferences.GetString gets both right value and null

Tags: android, json, null, sharedpreferences

good day! I'm just new to Android Programming and am currently stomped in a situation.

I have a SharedPreferences that stores a jSON Array.

```
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
editor.putString("inventoryKey", result);
editor.commit();
```

And then, when I call it back in another fragment.

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = this.getActivity().getSharedPreferences(MainActivity.MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String strJson = sharedpreferences.getString("inventoryKey", null);
```

I'm really stumped because when I run this fragment, I'm getting the NPE. I decided to put in the log cat the value of strJson using:

```
Log.i("info2",strJson);
```

And the following appears:

[image: link to picture of logcat].

Notice how it retrieves the current jSON then replaces it with null. According to the logcat, it happens exactly at the same time.

I'm quite stumped on this situation and I don't know why this is happening. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Edit: So, trying to find out the cause of this, I somehow did this

```
strJson = sharedpreferences.getString("inventoryKey", "hello");
Log.i("tester",strJson);
```

I was surprised, the logcat printed out the same. If it returns a null value, getString should get "hello" right? Instead, it still outputs null. So, is there a problem in putString rather than getString?

Comment: Next time, paste the text instead of linking an image. It makes it easier to work with.

Comment: @Machavity : Hello, sorry for that, I'll take note of it next time! Thank you!